# How do I view the files on my server?

Tags: php, laravel, github, laravel-5, linode

I am developing a web application using Laravel. I am using Laravel Forge with a Linode server and GitHub. My site is live at the moment. Whenever I change the code, I commit the changes using GitHub for Windows and then deploy the website on Laravel Forge.

One part of my application allows a user to upload a file. This works grand. I can upload a file and then download it from another computer on the website. However, I am not sure how to view the files on my server. They are not appearing on GitHub, and I cannot see anywhere on Laravel Forge to locate these files.

Anyone have any ideas?

The files are definitely there as I said, I can download and view the files once they are uploaded. I am storing them in a files folder in my public directory.

Comment: On your Linode box or Laravel Forge (i.e. wherever the files are being uploaded) , immediately after uploading a file, would it be possible to do a `find` to see the most recent (last 5 mins) modified files like so : `find -type f -mmin -5 -exec ls -l {} \;` ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that the versioner(Git) is ignoring your files.
Verify that where your files are stored and that the .gitignore files in each folder do not ignore them

```
*
/ Storage_path
Storage_file.extension
*.extension
```

Modify your corresponding .gitignore files and then commit everything